# In Django, how to sort instances of a child model class based on a field of its parent model class?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Here is the code:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.brand_name

class Product(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_name']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Let's say I have 2 brands, each with 2 products: Canon (camera, printer) and Samsung (laptop, tablet). When I create instances of Product, I will be able to sort them by their name on an Admin page: camera, laptop, printer, tablet. So far so good.
But what I actually would like to do is to sort them by [Brand + Product], so the sorted list should look like this: 'Canon - camera', 'Canon - printer', 'Samsung - laptop', 'Samsung - tablet'.

In order to do so I have to somehow access the value of the brand_name field from within the Product class. Is that possible and if so, how? Or is there an other/better way to achieve this type of sorting?

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['product_name', 'product'] #or ordering = ['product', 'product_name']
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.product_name) + " - " +str(self.product)
```

Comment: This is what I tried first but it did not work. As far as I understand (and I may be wrong because I'm a newbie in Django) _ordering_ is expecting a field it can sort on, such as CharField, whereas 'product' is simply a ForeignKey to the Brand class and it is not going to return brand_name. The problem is that Product is not a subclass of Brand; the only link between the 2 classes is the ForeignKey and I don't know if/how that can be used to retrieve the field values from the Brand class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in code as `somemodel.brand.brand_name`, and in a filter/query as `brand__brand_name`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this. Are you suggesting to implement the ordering in the model file or in the admin file?

Comment: Wherever it makes sense.

Comment: As I understand it the ordering has to happen in the model file (as the code above shows). The model that contains these 2 classes is called _store_. The problem is that if I call store.brand.brand_name inside the Product class I get an error (name 'store' is not defined). If I use brand.brand_name I have no error but it's empty. I'm missing something here.

Comment: ... Where did "store" come from? You have to use it from a `Product` model instance.